# Tab to exit quotes in Vim

Tags: vim

Usually when I code in Python, I have to create a dictionary, and I press `"` once and it creates `"|"`, being `|` my cursor.

I'm using `TAB` key in the [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) plugin to use snippets. I would like to press tab, when inside quotes after writing a string, that "exits" the quotes, but mantain snipMate. Example:

`"name|"`, and, pressing TAB, to become `"name"|`. So, mainly, when in **before a `"` in closing quotes, after pressing tab (or other combination possibly, since tab would conflict with a plugin or something), put cursor one side at right**. How should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[delimitMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2754) allows you to use `shift-tab` to exit quotes (or any other delimiters).

To exit a delimiter I'll usually just use `ctrl-o`, which puts me into normal mode for one action, then `A` to append text after the delimiter.

Comment: This is great... Someone told me about this plugin, it solves my problem in an elegant way. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated to the last version in it's git repository, and now this functionality is broken (it only works when I open a file without any extension). Do you know what can be?

Comment: i'm afraid i don't. i'd recommend contacting the developer directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely not to be compatible with other plugins, but you can try the following:

~/.vimrc:

```
inoremap " "<c-r>=TriggerSnippet()<cr>
```

Wherever your snippets are defined for python add a snippit like this:

```
snippet "
    "${1}"${2}
```

(the whitespace is a tab character, important when defining snippits)

This also <strike>may have</strike> probably has other side effects, I didn't test it too much.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Randy, but michaelmichael solution is simpler an delimitMate is a GREAT plugin.